# Stop lavaan's `sem()` function to print output

Tags: r, r-lavaan, sem

I am trying to run Monte Carlo simulations using R with the `lavaan` package and its function `sem()`. However, at every iteration, the output of `sem()` is showed, which is not very convenient. Is there a known way to stop that.

Here is a minimal example.

```
library(lavaan)
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
res = summary(sem("y ~ x"))
```

I have tried `suppressMessage()`, `invisible()` so far. I have found nothing in the various documentation.

Thank you,